# The method filter(Predicate<? super Employee>) in the type Stream<Employee> is not applicable for the arguments ((<no type> e) -> {})

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

How to set the values in Java 8 in filter ? I want to set emailId to null where firstName is Raj. How can I do that in Java8?

```
public class EmployeeDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Employee e1 = new Employee("John", "Kerr", "john.kerr@gmail.com");
        Employee e2 = new Employee("Parag", "Rane", "john.kerr@gmail.com");
        Employee e3 = new Employee("Raj", "Kumar", "john.kerr@gmail.com");
        Employee e4 = new Employee("Nancy", "Parate", "john.kerr@gmail.com");

        List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<>();
        employees.add(e1);
        employees.add(e2);
        employees.add(e3);
        employees.add(e4);

        employees.stream().filter(e -> {
            if(e.getFirstName().equals("Raj")) {
                e.setEmail(null);
            }
        }).
    }
}
```

Comment: You're missing a return statement in your filter lambda expression. You want `filter(e -> e.getFirstName().equals("Raj"))`

Comment: Suggestion: Avoid mutating elements within a stream.

Comment: `filter()` expects a bool result, you are not providing it as in your case nothing is being returned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Filter method should return `boolean` and I think shouldn't have any side effects. In your case simple loop will do the job:

```
for(Employee employee: employees) {
    if(e.getFirstName().equals("Raj")) {
        e.setEmail(null);
    }
}
```

But if you really want to use stream:

```
employees.stream() //get stream
    .filter(e -> e.getFirstName().equals("Raj")) //filter entries with first name Raj
    .forEach(e -> e.setEmail(null)); //for each of them set email to null
```

or (if you want to do process the whole list and return changed with all entries:

```
employees.stream() //get stream
    .map(e -> {
        if(e.getFirstName().equals("Raj")) {
            e.setEmail(null);
        }
        return e;
    })
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: I want all the without Raj emailIds as well , basically I want all the records.

Comment: There’s a closing bracket missing in `.forEach(e -> e.setEmail(null);`

Answer (score 2):

We can also use **[`Collectors.mapping`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#mapping-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-)** to check if the `firstName` is `Raj` and then set the `email` to `null` in the mapping function (1st argument) and then collect it in a new `List`(2nd argument):

```
employees.stream().collect(Collectors.mapping(emp -> {
          if("Raj".equals(emp.getFirstName())) {
              emp.setEmail(null); 
          } 
          return emp;
          }, Collectors.toList()));
```

And as nullpointer suggested, do not mutate the objects in the stream. You can use a copy constructor to make a copy of the `Employee` having `firstName` as `Raj` 
 and setting the `email` property to `null`:

```
employees.stream().collect(Collectors.mapping(emp -> {
          if("Raj".equals(emp.getFirstName())) {
              return new Employee(emp.getFirstName(), emp.getLastName(), null);
          }
          return emp;
          }, Collectors.toList()));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could on the other hand use [`List.replaceAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#replaceAll(java.util.function.UnaryOperator)) as :

```
employees.replaceAll(employee -> {
    if (employee.getFirstName().equals("Raj")) {
        employee.setEmail(null);
    }
    return employee;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `filter` and `map` of `Java8`, you can do it like:

```
employees.stream()
         .filter(e -> e.getFirstName().equalsIgnoreCase("Raj"))
         .map(e -> {
              e.setEmail(null);
              return e;
       }).findAny();
```